# How can I make readline add pre-"typed" text on terminal startup?

Tags: shell, terminal, readline

By pre-"typed", I mean the interactive console has code text waiting for the user to (edit and) run by simply pressing enter.

It looks like something readline should support, but a confirmation that it doesn't is good enough. At least I will know that installing an additional automation tool (like expect) is the only way.

Comment: Are you referring to using the readline library in an application of your own, or simply using a shell that makes use of readline for interactive input (such as bash's `read -ei "initial text"`)?

Comment: Exactly what `read -ei` does.

Comment: Why not just add it to the history list?  Then you just need to type up-enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, and is not per readline, but if python is an alternative (or some similar) one approach could be in the direction of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" Inject command to own command line """

import sys, fcntl, termios

def main():
    """ x """
    tty = sys.stdin
    old_attr = termios.tcgetattr(tty)
    new_attr = termios.tcgetattr(tty)
    # No echo please
    new_attr[3] &= ~termios.ECHO
    termios.tcsetattr(tty, termios.TCSANOW, new_attr)

    cmd = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
    for char in cmd:
        fcntl.ioctl(tty, termios.TIOCSTI, char)

    termios.tcsetattr(tty, termios.TCSANOW, old_attr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As in:

```
 script_name command to inject
```

Comment: It helps, and readline alternatives are welcome, especially if widely available on reasonably minimal systems. It fully deserved my upvote and it will become the accepted answer if I won't find any more basic option.

Comment: Just marked as accepted. Sorry for the delay. I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

Under ZShell, the `print -z` shell builtin can accomplish this.

```
% echo 'print -z "ls -l"' >> ~/.zshrc
% exec zsh
% ls -l
```

ZSH otherwise does not use `readline`, so any `readline` solution would doubtless "not work"™ for ZSH.